# Win Server 2008 Ping with wait command

Tags: windows-server-2008, ping

When use -w option with Ping command then Ping command should wait for the given time period before giving time out or destination host reachable error

I tried following command ping 192.168.151.45 -w 9000

I observed that it only waits for 4 second, what could be the reason for this

Comment: Request for those who voted down, have you tried it? It really does not waiting for more than 4 sec

Answer (score 0):

192.168.xx.xx is a local Adress...

> By default, ping waits 4,000 milliseconds (4 seconds) for each
>   response to be returned before displaying the "Request Timed Out"
>   message. If the remote system being pinged is across a high-delay
>   link, such as a satellite link, responses may take longer to be
>   returned. You can use the -w (wait) option to specify a longer
>   time-out.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737478(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I am already using it but the point is that it is not waiting for the given time period before giving time out